# Jedis key expiry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, jedis

I am trying to understand redis/jedis with spring. I am stuck somewhere where I can't able to expiry my key after certain period of time.

Can anyone please help ?

```
public class SessionCacheRepositoryImpl implements SessionCacheRepository {

    private static final String KEY = "Session";

    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
    private HashOperations hashOperations;

    @Autowired
    public SessionCacheRepositoryImpl(RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
        redisTemplate.expire(KEY, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void saveSession(final Session session) {
        hashOperations.put(KEY, session.getSessionID(), session);
    }
}
```

And this is my config class

```
private RedisTemplate<String, Object> template;

@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    jedisConFactory.setHostName("localhost");
    jedisConFactory.setPort(36919);
    return jedisConFactory;
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
    return template;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The call to `redisTemplate.expire(KEY, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` takes place in your init method which will be called after dependency injection takes place to initialize your class.  At this point, the key `Session` doesn't exist, so invoking the expire command has no effect.  See the Redis.io description for [EXPIRE](https://redis.io/commands/expire) for a complete description.  You could test this by capturing the return result from the expire command and log the results.

Instead of calling `expire` in the init method, you should call it in the save method to set the expiration time on your session when it is saved.

Comment: I forgot to mention in your code sample you always use the key `Session` - so all your saves will overwrite the same key.  Is that what you want?

Comment: No, I was just doing poc with that 
actually I was thinking of saving key as session ID, but now in put I have to define sessionId two times. One for key and one for identifier. 

`hashOperations.put(session.getSessionID(), session.getSessionID(), session);
redisTemplate.expire(session.getSessionID(), 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
`


is there any way that I can just use sessionID just as key and save my object?